# Swift - Building instagram-like user certification tableview for comments

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm building an Instagram-like certified-user feature on comments page.

For each comment, I need to check if the comment uploader is a certified user, and add user's certification icon right beside user's name.

My logic is following.

1 - Fetch all comments

2 - For each comment, check if commented user is certified user

3 - If comment uploader is certified, then mark commented-user as certified user

4 - Every time comments' data changes, reload tableView

My question is, would "reloading tableview" for every time comment changes cause huge performance issue?

Let's say there are 100 comments. Then, every time comment changes, tableView would reload data. So it'd reload 100 times with this logic.

If it is bad practice, how can I enhance my codes?

Following are my codes.

```
private var comments = [Comment]() {
    didSet { tableView.reloadData() }
}

private func fetchComments() {
    guard let questionId = question?.id else { return }

    API.shared.fetchComments(questionOrCommentId: questionId) { [weak self] comments in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        self.comments = comments

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.checkIfCommentsWritersAreVerified()
        }
    }
}

private func checkIfCommentsWritersAreVerified() {
    self.comments.forEach { comment in
        checkIfUserIsVerified(forUid: comment.uid, forCommentId: comment.commentId)
    }
}

private func checkIfUserIsVerified(forUid uid: String, forCommentId commentId: String = "") {
    
    API.shared.checkIfUserIsVerified(forUserId: uid) { [weak self] userIsVerified in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        if let index = self.comments.firstIndex(where: { $0.commentId == commentId }) {
            self.comments[index].userIsVerifiedTipper = userIsVerified
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what the data source of the table guy contains.

Comment: If you handle the back-end, might be interesting to have the "isCertified" with the user in the comment call already... Else, you can also reload a row instead of all the tableView...